# One texture render many times

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I have a small texture to tile the background of my game. So I want to draw the texture one by one. What shoud I do with libgdx opengl es.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please describe your problem as clear as possible. The better the question, the better the answers will be. Also make sure to search a solution for your problem, before posting a question. In your case i suggest to start reading the wiki (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki), to get some basic understanding of libgdx. The wiki will also show you how to draw with `SpriteBatch` and so it should help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Beside a proper problem statement, you should also provide the code, what you have tried so far to solve the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set you texture to repeat simply by:

```
Texture tilingTexture;
tilingTexture = new Texture("tiling_texture.png");
tilingTexture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);

//And draw it:

batch.draw(tilingTexture, 
xCoordWhereImageMustBeDisplayed, yCoordWhereImageMustBeDisplayed, 
xCoordOnImageItself, yCoordOnImageItself, 
widthOfImageToDisplay, heightOfImageToDisplay);
```

So basically if you want to scroll it infinitely you just have to increment the coords of the image itself.

```
    xIncrement += 10;

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(tilingTexture, 0, 0, xIncrement,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidh, Gdx.graphics.getHeight);
    batch.end();
```

If xIncrement is larger then the total width of the image it just wraps around. Of course you can do this yourself to reset xIncrement to 0 if it surpasses the image width. But with this wrapping method, if the hightOfImageToDisplay is larger then the image it will just tile next to each other.